# Is there a way to create CloudWatch Billing Alarms for Specific Linked Accounts

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Payer account with a linked account, in Organizations - Consolidated Billing.  What I am trying to do is create a CloudFormation template to create a Billing Alarm for each of the Linked Accounts.  Reason being, I want an alarm for the Estimated Charges at different levels depending on the type of account (e.g. Dev/Prod/Test).

I've searched through the Boto3 docs and AWS API docs, but there are no references to Linked Account metrics.  However, I **am** able to create it from the console.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_ListMetrics.html

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find documentation, but instead I created the Alarm with the Linked Accounts I then spun up an EC2 instance with permissions to run describe-alarms (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/describe-alarms.html).

This returned a JSON back to me which showed Linked Accounts as part of the Dimensions attribute for CloudWatch::Alarm.

Below is a CloudFormation snippet to create the Alarm specific to that Linked Account.

```
CloudWatchAlarm:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm'
    Properties:
      AlarmName: !Ref AlarmName
      AlarmDescription: !Join ["", ['CloudWatch Alarm to notify when the estimated charges >= $', !Ref ThresholdAmount, '.']]
      MetricName: EstimatedCharges
      Namespace: AWS/Billing
      Statistic: Maximum
      Period: '21600'
      EvaluationPeriods: '1'
      Threshold: !Ref ThresholdAmount
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      AlarmActions:
        - Ref: SNSTopic
      Dimensions:
        - Name: Currency
          Value: USD
        - Name: LinkedAccount
          Value: !Ref LinkedAccountNumber
      InsufficientDataActions:
        - Ref: SNSTopic
```